# Create array of strings from a string that contains certain (dual) characters

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have a string of words and mathematical/programmatically used symbols. For example, something like this:

```swift
let source = "a + b + 3 == c"
```

(Note: you cannot rely on spaces)

I also have an array of strings that I need to filter out of the source string:

```swift
let symbols = ["+", "-", "==", "!="]
```

Now, I need to **create an array of the matching items** (**with duplicates**). In this case that would be `["+", "+", "=="]`.

From what I've tried, `==` is two characters, so I **cannot** do the following:

```swift
let source = "a + b + 3 == c"
let symbols = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-=≠") // not '==' and '!=', but '=' and '≠' due to it being a CharacterSet

let operations = source
    .map { String($0) }
    .filter { char in symbols.contains(UnicodeScalar(char)!) }

print(operations)
// Output: ["+", "+", "=", "="]
// Needed: ["+", "+", "=="]
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is == really used in mathematics, I thought it was used only in programming languages?

Comment: I should've added that detail, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to threat your symbols as regular strings. Iterate each symbol and search it in your source. If you find a range append it to a collection, get the substring at that location and search again your string from the index after the range upperBound. When you reach the end of the string searching fro that symbol remove the substrings from your source. Try something like this:

```
var source = "a + b + 3 == c"
let symbols = ["+", "-", "==", "!="]

var results: [Substring] = []

for symbol in symbols {
    var startIndex = source.startIndex
    var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []
    while startIndex < source.endIndex,
          let range = source[startIndex...].range(of: symbol) {
        ranges.append(range)
        results.append(source[range])
        startIndex = source.index(after: range.upperBound)
    }
    for range in ranges.reversed() {
        source.removeSubrange(range)
    }
}

print(results)
```

this will print

> ["+", "+", "=="]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a parsing problem, which is to convert an input string into some kind of structured data. A nice way to do that is with *parser combinators*. Although the guts is complex, once set up, the example 'opStrings' function is simple to understand and it's easy to extend.

```
struct Parser<A> {
    let run: (inout Substring) -> A?

    static func always<A>(_ a: A) -> Parser<A> {
        .init { _ in a }
    }

    static var never: Parser {
        .init { _ in nil }
    }

    func map<B>(_ f: @escaping (A) -> B) -> Parser<B> {
        Parser<B> { str -> B? in
            self.run(&str).map(f)
        }
    }
    
    func flatMap<B>(_ f: @escaping (A) -> Parser<B>) -> Parser<B> {
        Parser<B> { str -> B? in
            let original = str
            let matchA = self.run(&str)
            let parserB = matchA.map(f)
            guard let matchB = parserB?.run(&str) else {
                str = original
                return nil
            }
            return matchB
        }
    }

    func run(_ str: String) -> (match: A?, rest: Substring) {
        var str = str[...]
        let match = self.run(&str)
        return (match, str)
    }
}

func prefix(while p: @escaping (Character) -> Bool) -> Parser<Substring> {
    Parser<Substring> { str in
        let prefix = str.prefix(while: p)
        str.removeFirst(prefix.count)
        return prefix
    }
}

func literalString(_ p: String) -> Parser<String?> {
    Parser<String?> { str in
        guard str.hasPrefix(p) else { return nil }
        str.removeFirst(p.count)
        return p
    }
}

func literal(_ str: String) -> Parser<Void> {
    literalString(str).map {
        _ in ()
    }
}

func oneOrMore<A>(_ predicate: @escaping (Character) -> Bool,
                 mapped f: @escaping (Substring) -> A) -> Parser<A> {
    prefix(while: predicate)
        .flatMap { $0.isEmpty ? .never : .always(f($0)) }
}

let oneOrMoreDecimals = oneOrMore((\.isNumber), mapped: Double.init)
    .flatMap { d -> Parser<Double> in
        guard let d = d else { return .never }
        return .always(d)
    }

func oneOf<A>(_ ps: [Parser<A>]) -> Parser<A> {
    Parser<A> { str -> A? in
        for p in ps {
            if let match = p.run(&str) {
                return match
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let whitespace = oneOf([
        literal(" "),
        literal("\t"),
        literal("\n")
    ])

let identifier = prefix(while: { ($0.isLetter && $0.isASCII) || $0.isNumber })
    .flatMap { str -> Parser<String> in
    guard let first = str.first else { return Parser.never }
        return first.isNumber ? .never : .always(String(str))
}

let literalNumber = prefix(while: { $0.isNumber })
    .flatMap { str -> Parser<Double> in
        guard let value = Double(str) else { return Parser.never }
        return .always(value)
    }

func skip<T, U>(_ p: Parser<T>) -> Parser<U?> {
    p.map { _ in nil }
}

struct Example {
    enum Token {
        case minus
        case plus
        case equal
        case equalEqual
        case notEqual
        case identifier(String)
        case number(Double)
    }

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case unexpectedInput
    }
    
    let input: String

    func run<T>(_ parsers: [Parser<T?>]) throws -> [T] {
        var source = Substring(input)
        var results: [T] = []
        
        while let token = oneOf(parsers).run(&source) {
            if let token = token {
                results.append(token)
            }
        }
        
        guard source.isEmpty else {
            throw Error.unexpectedInput
        }
        
        return results
    }
    
    func tokenize() throws -> [Token] {
        let tokenizers: [Parser<Token?>] = [
            literal("-").map { .minus },
            literal("+").map { .plus },
            literal("==").map { .equalEqual },
            literal("!=").map { .notEqual },
            literal("=").map { .equal },
            identifier.map { .identifier($0) },
            oneOrMoreDecimals.map { .number($0) },
            skip(whitespace)
        ]
        
        return try run(tokenizers)
    }
    
    func opStrings() throws -> [String] {
        try run([
            literalString("-"),
            literalString("+"),
            literalString("=="),
            literalString("!="),
            literalString("="),
            skip(identifier),
            skip(oneOrMoreDecimals),
            skip(whitespace),
        ] as [Parser<String?>])
    }
}

do {
    let example = Example(input: "a + b + 3 == c")
    // let tokens = try example.tokenize()
    print(try example.opStrings()) // ["+", "+", "=="]
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```